# Android Homescreen touch Event Places a view on it , And another Touch Event destoys the View

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, homescreen

I have android Homescreen TouchEvent,Basically what i wanted to achieve was a view should come form down of the screen and cover the Homescreen . And the view should be closed on another touch event.

Now all the back button,homebutton,recent button should be functional
and when anyone pressed the homescrren should come.And my app should not be in recent list .

i Have seen this functionality on a particluar app.I checked its log by
Adb Logcat | Grep -i activityManager . but found no activiyy being used

I used system overlay window but my Homescreen button ,recent and back button don't work.

Any Help or Idea would be Highly apreciated,i am stuck and dont know how to proceed